# override form's clean method to customize error messages

Tags: python, django, forms, overriding

I'm having trouble overriding clean method of a built-in Django form ([django.contrib.auth.SetPasswordForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/)). This form has two fields: new_password1 and new_password2.

so in my views.py I call the customized form (`MySetPasswordForm`):

```
def reset_confirm(request, uidb64=None, token=None):
    return password_reset_confirm_delegate(request,
        template_name='app/reset_confirm.html',
        set_password_form = MySetPasswordForm, uidb64=uidb64, 
        token=token, post_reset_redirect=reverse('main_page'))
```

In my forms.py: I want to define my own clean method to show my customized error messages. here's how I wrote `MySetPasswordForm`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import SetPasswordForm
class MySetPasswordForm(SetPasswordForm):
    error_messages = {  'password_mismatch': _("Missmatch!"),  }

    def clean(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1', '')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password2', '')

        print password1  #prints user's entered value
        print password2  #prints nothing!!
        print self.data['new_password2']  #prints user's entered value

        if password1 == '':
            self._errors["new_password1"] = ErrorList([u"enter pass1!"])

        if password2 == '':
            self._errors["new_password2"] = ErrorList([u"enter pass2"])

        elif password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                    code='password_mismatch',
                )
        return self.cleaned_data
```

The problem is that when the user enter the repeat password wrong, instead of getting `"Missmatch" error`, it gives `"enter pass2"`! Also `print password2` doesn't print user's entered value for password2.

What am I doing wrong in this code?! and what is the best way to do customized error messages?

p.s. using the original SetPasswordForm in the view works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SetPasswordForm` checks that `new_password1` and `new_password2` match in the [`clean_new_password2`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5d9034bc92e9def0785a3b7cd9ca65e284db0191/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L325) method.

When the passwords do not match, `new_password2` is not included in `self.cleaned_data`, so you can't access it in the `clean` method.

If you want to override the error message for mismatched passwords, then setting it in the `error_messages` dict is the correct approach. I would then remove the `clean` method from your form.

If you need a different `required` error message for each field, you could set it in the `__init__` method.

```
class MySetPasswordForm(SetPasswordForm):
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': _("Missmatch!"),  
        'required': _("Please enter a password"),  # If you do not require the fieldname in the error message
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySetPasswordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['new_password1'].error_messages['required'] = _("enter pass1!")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so how can I set the `error_messages` dict?

Comment: You are already setting the `error_messages` dict in your question. I've added an example.

Comment: awesome tnx. Guess I'm still a newby in using forms :)
I also need min-length validation on my field, can I do this validation using error_messages (if yes how?) or do I have to use the clean method?

Comment: It would be better to use Django's [password validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation) instead of checking the length in the form.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the clean method of form super method `def clean_new_password2(self)` all ready is called, so `self.cleaned_data['new_password2']` is empty You need override the clean_new_password2 in your form, look for source [auth forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/)

```
class MySetPasswordForm(SetPasswordForm):

    def clean_new_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password2')
        if password1 and password2:
            if password1 != password2:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                    code='password_mismatch',
                )
        return password2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can I override `clean_new_password2` and do other validations too?

Comment: what about the other field validations? Do I need another clean method for them?

Comment: only if you want to customize them.